# ATIConfig returning incorrect graphics cards

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics

I just upgraded to 14.04 (from 12.04) which ended up being a bit of a hassle. I now have almost everything working, except that my second graphcis card is being a bit weird.

if I run `aticonfig --list-adapters` I get:

```
* 0. 01:00.0 Supported device 6811
  1. 04:00.0 Supported device 6811

* - Default adapter
```

Same thing if I run `sudo aticonfig --list-adapters`

if I run `aticonfig --initial --adapter=all` I get:

```
Found fglrx primary device section
Found fglrx primary device section
 Unable to find any supported Screen sections
```

If I run `sudo aticonfig --od-getclocks --adapter=all` I get:

```
Default Adapter - Supported device 6811
                        Core (MHz)    Memory (MHz)
       Current Clocks :    300           150
         Current Peak :    975           1400
Configurable Peak Range : [300-1050]     [150-1500]
             GPU load :    7%
ERROR - Get clocks failed for Adapter 1 - Supported device 6811
```

Any idea why I get that error - and how do I fix it? There is currently no monitor plugged into the second card, is this the issue?

Comment: I find the answer, this did it for me: http://prismsoul.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/installing-ubuntus-fglrx-proprietary-catalyst-drivers/